Toast Notification not showing when replacing file in Upload Compnent of Ant design
I'm using Ant design's Upload Component in my code to enable file uploading and replacing.
Following are the props I've defined:
const uploadProps = {
    beforeUpload: async (file) => {
      // console.log('file:', file);
      const allowedExtensions = ["pdf", "docx"];
      const fileExtension = file.name.split(".").pop().toLowerCase();
      if (file.size < 50 * 1000) {
        toast.error('CV file must be at least 50KB in size', {theme: 'dark'})
      } else if (file.size > 5 * 1000000) {
        toast.error('CV file cannot exceed 5MB in size', {theme: 'dark'})
      } else {
        if (!allowedExtensions.includes(fileExtension)) {
          toast.error("Only PDF and DOCX files are allowed.", {theme: 'dark'});
          return Upload.LIST_IGNORE;
        }

        if (isUploaded) {
          toast.error("You can upload only one CV at a time.", {theme: 'dark'});
          return Upload.LIST_IGNORE;
        }
        setLoading(true);

        try {
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("file", file);
          const response = await axios.post(
            `${import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL_PYTHON}/upload-cv`,
            formData,
            {
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
              },
            }
          );

          if (response.status === 200 && response.data) {
            const { _id } = response.data.data;
            const { fileSize } = response.data.data;
            setUserData({ fileSize: fileSize });
            setRecordId(_id);
            setUploadedFile(file.name);
            setIsUploaded(true);
            setLoading(false);
          } else {
            toast.error("Failed to upload CV. Please try again.");
            setLoading(false);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          toast.error("An error occurred while uploading.");
          console.error("Upload error:", error);
        }
      }

      return false; // Prevent automatic upload
    },
  };

  const handleDeleteCV = () => {
    setUploadedFile(null); // Remove uploaded file name
    setRecordId(null); // Reset record ID
    setIsUploaded(false); // Mark as not uploaded
    // toast.info("CV has been deleted.");
  };

  const replaceProps = {
    beforeUpload: async (file) => {
      const allowedExtensions = ["pdf", "docx"];
      const fileExtension = file.name.split(".").pop().toLowerCase();

      if (file.size < 50 * 1000) {
        toast.error('CV file must be at least 50KB in size', {theme: 'dark'})
        console.log('replace prop min size');
        return Upload.LIST_IGNORE;
      } else if (file.size > 5 * 1000000) {
        toast.error('CV file cannot exceed 5MB in size', {theme: 'dark'})
        console.log('replace prop max size');
        return Upload.LIST_IGNORE;
      } else if (!allowedExtensions.includes(fileExtension)) {
        toast.error("Only PDF and DOCX files are allowed.", {theme: 'dark'});
        return Upload.LIST_IGNORE;
      } else {
        if (isUploaded) {
          handleDeleteCV();
        }
        setLoading(true);

        try {
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append("file", file);
          const response = await axios.post(
            `${import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL_PYTHON}/upload-cv`,
            formData,
            {
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
              },
            }
          );

          if (response.status === 200 && response.data) {
            const { _id } = response.data.data;
            setRecordId(_id);
            setUploadedFile(file.name);
            setIsUploaded(true); // Mark CV as uploaded
            // toast.success("CV uploaded successfully!");
            // handleDeleteCV()
            setLoading(false);
          } else {
            toast.error("Failed to upload CV. Please try again.", {theme: 'dark'});
            setLoading(false);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          toast.error(error || "An error occurred while uploading.", {theme: 'dark'});
          console.error("Upload error:", error);
          setLoading(false);
        }
        return false; // Prevent automatic upload
      }
    },
  };

But the issue I'm facing is that the error toast appears if the selected file isn't a valid (less than 50kb or greater than 5MB) while uploading (using 'uploadProps') but it doesn't work when I try to replace the file with invalid file (using 'replaceProps'). Instead, all the error toasts show up when I select a valid file.
I made two different props for uploading and replacing.
I tried to add
return false 

and
return Upload.LIST_IGNORE 

but didn't work.
